# Flutter Textformfield should be responsive to typing and error

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-textformfield

I've often seen where fields are responsive when users are typing, giving realtime feedback. An example is when I'm typing confirm password or email, if the confirm password or email hasn't matched the password while typing it returns error by marking turning the border of the field red until it matches the correct input. I have written this code, how do I improve the code to be responsive as described.

```
  Widget _buildConfirmPasswordTF() {
    return Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, children: <Widget>[
      // Text('Password', style: kLabelStyle,),
      SizedBox(height: 10.0),
      Container(alignment: Alignment.centerLeft, decoration: kBoxDecorationStyle, height: 60.0, child: TextFormField(
        validator: ( confirmPassword ){
          if ( confirmPassword.trim() != _password.isValidPassword ) {
            return null;
          }  else {
            return 'Password doesn\'t match';
            }
        },
        obscureText: true, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontFamily: 'OpenSans',),
        decoration: InputDecoration(border: InputBorder.none, contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 14.0),
          prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.lock, color: Colors.white,),
          hintText: 'Enter Confirm Password',
          hintStyle: kHintTextStyle,
          errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder( borderSide: BorderSide( color: Colors.red ) ),
          focusedErrorBorder: OutlineInputBorder( borderSide: BorderSide( color: Colors.red ) )
        ),
      ),
      ),
    ],
    );
  }
```

This is where I set the hintText

```
final kHintTextStyle = TextStyle(
  color: Colors.white54,
  fontFamily: 'OpenSans',
);
```

This is where I set the labelStyle

```
final kLabelStyle = TextStyle(
  color: Colors.white,
  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
  fontFamily: 'OpenSans',
);
```

This is where I set the border decoration

```
final kBoxDecorationStyle = BoxDecoration(
  color: Color(0xFF6CA8F1),
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
  boxShadow: [
    BoxShadow(
      color: Colors.black12,
      blurRadius: 6.0,
      offset: Offset(0, 2),
    ),
  ],
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need `autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,` pass this in textformfield.

Comment: Thanks. It's spot on.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with a `Form()` providing it a `key` and a `autoValidateMode` to make sure the fields have value or that the value is something you except, you can add another field to confirm the passwork or email and compare the value of the field in the `onChanged` with the value of the other email field to make sure they match.

```
  import 'package:email_validator/email_validator.dart';

  final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final _emailController = TextEditingController();
  final _passwordController = TextEditingController();
  bool isValid = false;

_emailController.addListener(
  () {
    //With this, you can "listen" all the changes on your text while
    //you are typing on input
    //use setState to rebuild the widget

    if (EmailValidator.validate(_emailController.text)) {
      setState(() {
        isValid = true;
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        isValid = false;
      });
    }
  },
);

              Form(
                key: formKey,
                autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          horizontal: size.width * 0.105),
                      child: TextFormField(
                        validator: (value) =>
                            !EmailValidator.validate(value)
                                ? 'Enter a valid email'
                                : null,
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        controller: _emailController,
                        decoration: kInputDecoration.copyWith(
                            hintText: 'Enter your email'),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 18,
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          horizontal: size.width * 0.105),
                      child: TextFormField(
                        obscureText: true,
                        validator: (value) =>
                            value.isEmpty ? 'Enter your password' : null,
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        controller: _passwordController,
                        decoration: kInputDecoration.copyWith(
                            hintText: 'Enter your password'),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
```

Comment: Thanks for this elaborate answer